# Conceptual differences between Graph Homomorphism and Graph Rewriting

Tags: graph-theory

Apologies in advance if this question is meaningless.

On my first reading, both Graph Homomorphism and Graph rewriting seem to be concerned with Graph transformations. I am unable to see what problems each of them solves and how their applications differ.
Can someone please help me with this ?

What are the conceptual similarities and differences between Graph Homomorphism and Graph Rewriting? What problems/applications each is concerned with ?

Regards.

Comment: If you mean graph rewriting in the context of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_rewriting then it looks like graph rewriting is an example of a graph homomorphism, or at least a pair of such morphisms. Graph homomorphism are the morphism in the category of graphs (the objects of this category are the graphs), which makes them a general abstract mathematical object. Seems to me like graph rewritings have more of an application in algorithm design whereby graphs merely represent the state of the computation.

Comment: @Condo Thank you for your reply. I have some data files which i want to load as graphs and want to render them as svg. I would to need combine some vertices in source graph to one single node in svg and also i might need to seperate a single source vertex to multiple target nodes. Instead of hand coding  all this to imperatively render them as svg, i was wondering if there are any formal methods to do this.  Would Graph Homomorphisms provide any help in this regard?

Comment: hmmm I certainly don't know perhaps this would be a more appropriate question for a more computer science/programming forum...